# How to set box-sizing model for mxGraph vertexes?

Tags: javascript, css, flowchart, mxgraph

When using `mxHierarchicalLayout` together with `strokeWidth > 1` borders for all topmost and leftmost vertexes will be displayed incorrectly. See the screenshot below:

[image]

That is because border width doesn't count to total vertex height/width.

Is there a possibility to set box sizing model for `mxGraph` the same way `box-sizing: border-box;` works for CSS?

If no, is it possible to move entire graph context downward or leftward after it has been laid by layout engine?

Comment: "If no, is it possible to move entire graph context downward or leftward after it has been laid by layout engine" - `Yes there are workarounds for this`, concerning the first scale of your question, what do would you like exactly to do? Make all your vertexes same size regardless of their text-length?

Comment: I just want that border of top most vertex is drawn correctly. It gets Y position 0 after hierarchical layout and therefore thick border is drawn only partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the borders are drawn correctly but the problem is that the leftmost and topmost vertices' borders get hidden because they `are placed "behind" the canvas`, so a workaround would be to `move your whole graph a little to the bottom and to the right dependening on your needs`. Code to do this:

```
let layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
graph.model.beginUpdate();
let children = graph.getChildCells();
graph.moveCells(children, undefined , 20);  // assuming you want to "move your graph 20px to the bottom"
graph.model.endUpdate();
```

You can use the same function to move `horizontally` your graph (left-right), check the 
`moveCells` function of `mxGraph.js`

`mxGraph.prototype.moveCells = function(cells, dx, dy, clone, target, evt, mapping)`